Is it safe to restrain my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to amd64 architecture to save space?
I want to save disk space in /var/lib/apt/lists/, so I  restrained my /etc/apt/sources.list file to amd64 architecture like this:
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main universe restricted multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main multiverse restricted universe

Is it safe to do that?

In my opinion; SAFE YES, could there be problems, also yes (but that will depend on how the system is used; what packages are added etc or context)


I want to save disk space in /var/lib/apt/lists/ so I restrained my /etc/apt/sources.list file to amd64 architecture like this ?

Yes, go for it if you want to keep less files in /var/lib/apt/lists/.
You also need to do 1 time:
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update

after altering /etc/apt/sources.list to re-create the filelist from your sources.list.
